# Git EndOfLine woes -> Given a windows only project, how can i just tell git to not do anything?

Tags: visual-studio, git

OK -> so I've got some windows only projects. I'm sick of having crlf set to auto and I'm always getting frigging warnings about line endings, etc.

I want all my files to end with the windows only CRLF. I use visual studio and all our team uses visual studio.

What setting do I need to set in my `.gitattributes` file please?

*NOTE: please don't turn this into a 'but some people might use this outside of VS / on mono, etc. This is for a private company repo*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git does nothing by default but most windows Git installations set `core.autocrlf` to `true` by default. To undo this setting you can do:

```
git config --system --unset core.autocrlf
```

or to explicitly disable it for your user:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

In your git attributes, to force no line ending normalization on any clone of your repository, you can use this, which means: "all files are non-text files".

```
* -text
```

Comment: Thanks @charlesBailey! So, firstly, i need to set `autocrlf` to `FALSE`? If so, can i just do this in my `.gitattributes`? And if yes, would i also need to do  `* -text`?

Comment: No, `core.autocrlf` is a config setting; not an attribute. You only need to do one.

Comment: Then I should go with `* -text` because i want this to be a PROJECT settings, regardless of what setting the project members have set, on their individual settings. Ie. this `.gitattributes` setting will override theirs/take presedence. Sounds about right, then?